# How do I trigger a mysql statement with javascript onclick?

Tags: javascript, mysql

Well the issue I'm facing is I wish to update a mysql record whenever someone clicks on a thumbs up button but I'm rather new to javascript so it would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

My website is built using php if that helps.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to send an AJAX request when you click. On the server side, there should be a URL that would listen for this request & will execute the query accordingly.

I hate to give an example from w3schools but still have a [look at this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp).

**EDIT:** To the OP, you can take the idea from the example, but it is strongly discouraged to use GET request. See Crowdner's comment.

Comment: Oh ok great, can the listening file be php and pass variables to it?

Comment: Ajax is **not** required. It's convenient, on browsers that have JavaScript enabled (98% or so do), but it's not the only way to do this.

Comment: Yeah, you can do a GET/POST to the URL. The example I gave uses GET request. So, while doing a GET/POST, you can send the data you want. Have a look at http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree. It's not required but it's looks *elegant* that way.

Comment: @AbhijeetRastogi: *"The example I gave uses GET request."* Using GET for a state-changing operation is a bad idea. GET operations must be [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). Operations that change things must be `POST` (or `PUT`, `DELETE`, or other state-changing HTTP verbs).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for the insight. *THAT's* the reason I wasn't giving a link to w3schools.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices, both of which consist of a client-side piece and a server-side piece:

1. Post a form to a hidden `iframe`, with the "thumbs up" button being a submit control. No JavaScript required, just put the hidden `iframe` on the page with a `name`, and have the form's `target` point to that name. The form's `action` would be the server page that records the click.
2. Have the "thumbs up" fire a JavaScript click handler, which fires off an [ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) POST to your server page that records the click.

---

Side note: If you're going to be doing a lot of client-side JavaScript programming, I strongly recommend investing some time in learning JavaScript and the [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/). Picking it up as you go without spending just a little time up front learning things properly will cost you in the long run. I also recommend using a good library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). You can do everything with your own code, of course, but using a widely-used library lets you leverage the work of others, smoothing out browser differences and providing some very useful utility functionality.

Comment: +1 for the sneaky no JavaScript approach.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it helps, that you are using PHP. Javascript can't access MySQL database, because JS is client side and MySQL is server side you will have to use AJAX to call a PHP script who will do rest of the work you can use the jQuery.post function.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 1):

```
function updateSQL() {
   window.location.href = "update.php?id=1";
}
```

When click on the button you can redirecto same page and using $_GET you can validate for the sent parameter. Then you can fire the SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

The main way of doing this is through AJAX. You can use an AJAX call to asynchronously call a method on your server. So in your case PHP.

Creating an AJAX call which works cross browser can be a tedious task. That's why i recommend a library instead like jQuery (thats where i'm famliliar with). There are s everal others like Prototype, mootools etc.

A simple example in jQuery would be:

```
// Your jQuery method

S('myLink').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax/test.html',
      success: function(data) {
        alert('The server replied: '+data);
      }
    });
}

<!-- In your html (no need for an onclick event, jQuery handles that for you) -->
<a href="#" id="myLink">Get data</a>
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/